# lua:15: unexpected symbol near '['

Tags: lua, torch

I am trying to write a function to create a CNN model. I get the following error whenever I run the script:

> lua:15: unexpected symbol near '['

```lua
require('torch')

require('nn')

function CeateNvidiaModel()

    --The Nvidia model
    --Input dimensions
    local n_channels = 3
    local height = 66
    local width = 200
    local nvidia_model = nn.Sequential();
    --nvida_model:add(nn.Normalize()
    --Convolutional Layers
    nvidia_model:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(n_channels, 24, 5, 5, [2], [2]))
    nvidia_model:add(nn.ELU(true))
    nvidia_model:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(24, 36, 5, 5, [2], [2]))
    nvidia_model:add(nn.ELU(true))
    nvidia_model:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(36, 48, 5, 5, [2], [2]))
    nvidia_model:add(nn.ELU(true))
    nvidia_model:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(48, 64, 3, 3))
    nvidia_model:add(nn.ELU(true))
    nvidia_model:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(64, 64, 3, 3))
    nvidia_model:add(nn.ELU(true))
    -- Flatten Layer
    nvidia_model:add(nn.Reshape(1164))
    -- FC Layers
    nvida_model:add(nn.Linear(1164, 100))
    nvidia_model:add(nn.ELU(true))
    nvida_model:add(nn.Linear(100, 50))
    nvidia_model:add(nn.ELU(true))
    nvida_model:add(nn.Linear(50, 10))
    nvidia_model:add(nn.ELU(true))
    nvida_model:add(nn.Linear(10, 1))
    return nvida_model
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are confusing `[]` and `{}`. In many other languages, you write array literals as `[1, 2, 3]`, but in Lua `[` and `]` are only used for indexing; to declare an "array literal", you write `{1, 2, 3}` (because arrays in Lua are just tables).

The error message is a bit misleading; it says unexpected symbol *near* '[', but in reality the `[` *is* the unexpected symbol.

Comment: the error msg might be misleading for a beginner, but it is precise. you have a list of expressions and Lua tries to resolve them. it starts inside the brackets, then checks what is to its left. it expects a name. finds a comma. although I'm confused because it should be next to `[` instead of `]`. Maybe a typo in the OP?